# Set default value for select field jquery filter data attribute

Tags: jquery, data-binding

```
filterJobs: function()
{
    var team = $('#selectOne').val();
    var specialty = $('#selectTwo').val();
    var level = $('#selectThree').val();
    //var defSelectTeam=

    $('.jobs').hide()
            .filter('[data-team="' + team + '"][data-specialization="' + specialty + '"][data-level="' + level + '"]')
            .show();
    var newNumJobs = $('.jobs:visible').length;
    $('table:visible:odd').css({'background-color': ' #F1F1F1'});
    $('table:visible:even').css({'background-color': '#FFFFFF'});
    if (newNumJobs <= this.pageSize)
    {
        $("#dvJobs span").text("Showing " + newNumJobs + " of " + newNumJobs + " jobs");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#dvJobs span").text("Showing " + this.pageSize + " of " + newNumJobs + " jobs");
    }

    this.buildPaginator(newNumJobs);
},
```

Hi guys any clue how to modify this filtering function for select filtering right now it works, I need to set a default value that shows all options before the filtering on change? I just need to be pointed in the right general direction, I'm crap at js, but trying to improve. Thanks in advance,
 The html is this//////, it works by taking the data attributes off a table, that part works fine, just need to set a default value, I was thinking of setting a couple of data attrs, but that seems messy. or setting an if block that checks the value, if its 'select one' show all. Sorry for rambling on.

```
<select id="selectOne">
    <option value="Select One">Select One </option>
    <option value="Engineering">Engineering </option>
    <option value="SoftwareDevelopment" >Software Development</option>
    <option value="HumanResources" >Human Resources</option>
    <option value="MarkettingAndSales">Marketting and Sales</option>
    <option value="Administrative">Administrative</option>
    <option value="Others">Others</option>
</select>
<label>Specialty:</label>
<select id="selectTwo">
    <option class="Select One" >Select One </option>
    <option class="MarkettingAndSales" value="Sales">Sales </option>
    <option class="HumanResources" value="Recruitment">Recruitment </option>
    <option class="Administrative" value="OfficeGeneral">Office General </option>
    <option class="Engineering SoftwareDevelopment" value="WebDevelopment">Web Development </option>
    <option  class="SoftwareDevelopment" value="ApplicationDevelopment">Application Development </option>
    <option class="SoftwareDevelopment" value="UIUXDesign">UI/UX Design</option>
    <option class="Others" value="ScientificResearch">Scientific Research</option>
    <option  class="Engineering Others" value="ComputerHardwareNetworking">Computer Hardware  Networking</option>
    <option  class="Others" value="Others">Others</option>
</select>
<label>Level:</label>
<select id="selectThree">
    <option>Senior</option>
    <option>Intermediate</option>
    <option>Junior</option>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance.
UPDATE: I modified it a bit to show the pagination, but I guess I am using the val function wrong in the if/else block?

```
filterJobs: function()
{
    var team = $('#selectOne').val();
    var specialty = $('#selectTwo').val();
    var level = $('#selectThree').val();
    var newNumJobs = $('.jobs:visible').length;
    if (team === 'SelectOne' && specialty === 'SelectOne')
    {
        $('.jobs').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('.jobs').hide()
                .filter('[data-team="' + team + '"][data-specialization="' + specialty + '"][data-level="' + level + '"]')
                .show();

        $('table:visible:odd').css({'background-color': ' #F1F1F1'});
        $('table:visible:even').css({'background-color': '#FFFFFF'});
    }
    if (newNumJobs <= this.pageSize)
    {
        $("#dvJobs span").text("Showing " + newNumJobs + " of " + newNumJobs + " jobs");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#dvJobs span").text("Showing " + this.pageSize + " of " + newNumJobs + " jobs");
    }


    this.buildPaginator(newNumJobs);
}
```

For clarification, I've added the tabe being filtered, hope that helps understand my question.

```
<table data-team="<?php print $name['team']; ?>" data-specialization="<?php print $name['speciality']; ?>" data-level="<?php print $name['level']; ?>" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="670px" class="jobs"><tr><td>
    <tr><td colspan="4"><strong>Research Assistant</strong></td>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="100">Location : </td>
        <td colspan="3">Madrid</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Job Code : </td>
        <td width="460">6767676</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `data-` attribute seems like as good an approach as any other. Not clear what the default issue is

Comment: The default issue was that, on load the filter is called, so no options show, I want everything loaded before I start calling the filter function.

Comment: only activate the filter in a `change` handler for the selects. Doubtful you need to run it when page loads unless you have conditions where page loads with preset options selected

Comment: creating a demo in jsfiddle.net would definitely help

Comment: Thats the case now.///// Here is the code that binds on page load////// $('#selectOne').change(this.filterJobs.bind(this)).change();
   $('#selectTwo').change(this.filterJobs.bind(this)).change();
   $('#selectThree').change(this.filterJobs.bind(this)).change();

Comment: dont quite know how to edit it with a default show all

Comment: create demo regardless... we have no markup to see how this works

Answer (score 1):

I'm not POSITIVE I understand your question, but if you just want a default selection for the dropdowns, jQuery is not required. Just add `selected='selected'` to the option you want to set as the default in the html. Like this:

```
<select id="selectOne">
    <option value="Select One">Select One </option>
    <option value="Engineering" selected="selected">Engineering </option>
    ...etc...
```

In this case, too, you could get rid of the "Select One" option and make that a label or something instead.

EDIT:

You can also apply the selected filter dynamically using jQuery if you need to:

```
$('#optionId').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

EDIT 2:

Ok, read the other comments on the original question. I think I see better what the issue was. I agree that doing the filtering in a change handler would be best. Something like:

```
$('#selectOne, #selectTwo, #selectThree').change(filterJobs);
```

Additionally, if you need to execute this filtering on page load, set 'selected' as per above and in jQuery call

```
$('#selectWhichever').trigger('change');
```

which will trigger the change handler without needing to actually select a value.

Comment: Okay :-) Thanks! combining your sugestion with my code changes, gives me exactly what I want! thanks a lot :-)

Comment: well, has a few weird quirks like this..... for instance  the filtering function is failing now.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do? I had a hard time figuring it out in your code, since some seems to be left out (for instance, I don't see anything with a class of "jobs"). EDIT: Oh, I found it.

Comment: Lol.... Okay,  the thing is this is a snippet from the js class that powers the  ui/ux aspect of the application, the table is dynamically generated, so if I were to place the code as it were here or in js fiddle it would be quite lenghty.